# Trying out for a cloud function to trigger when a file is created in the good bucket

Tags: google-cloud-functions

I am looking for storage triggered cloud function which can dynamically create big query table using python code .

Can some suggest??

Comment: why is this tagged under big-query?

Comment: Open Cloud Storage in GCP Console. Then using the three dots at right hand side, click on the 'Process with Cloud Function' option. You will get the rest options there.

Answer (score 1):

Choose `Trigger type = Cloud Storage` and `Event type = Finalize / Create` when creating cloud function.

[image]